# How to check if a monitor is plugged in? (Linux)

Tags: c++, linux

This is not a duplicate of other questions as I want to get in done in linux.

I am doing image processing on a development board and for this, I am testing/developing on my laptop. In OpenCV, there is `imshow()` which is used to display the image. But it will work only if a monitor is there. So I want to check if a monitor is present before calling it, so that it will be called when the code is run on PCs and not when it is running on the board.

How do I get this done?

```
...
...
if(<only-if-monitor-is-present>)
  imshow(img);
...
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to do it:

```
int MonitorNotPresent = system("xset -q | tail -n1 | grep On");
if(!WEXITSTATUS(MonitorNotPresent))
  imshow(img)
```

Headers used:

```
cstdlib
```

Comment: I suppose You should accept one of the answers if it provides enough informations for You.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [`xset (user preference utility for X)`](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/xset.1.html) with `-q` flag:

> The q option gives you information on the current settings.

I've written simple program that uses that command and parses an output:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

bool is_monitor_present() {
    int result = system("xset -q | tail -n1 | grep 'Monitor is On'");
    return result == 0;
}

int main() {
    bool found  = is_monitor_present();

    if(found) {
        std::cout << "Monitor is present." << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Monitor absent." << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Execution on the Linux Ubuntu 15.04 on my laptop results with output:

> Monitor present.

Same code on my Raspberry with up-to-date-or-almost-up-to-date Raspbian:

> xset:  unable to open display ""
>
> Monitor absent.

I do not recommend to use this code on production, but for some tests seems to work fine. At least at Debians.

Comment: At lease use `popen("xset -q | tail -n1","r")`  with `pclose`, not `system` !

Comment: This depends on DPMS being enabled on the monitor, as with DPMS disabled it misses out the "Monitor is On" line entirely.